# How to access an element by class in watir

Tags: html, watir

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li>
    <a class="trg-login" href="#">
    <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>Login
    </a>
```

Above is my code so how to access the class element in the watir .

Comment: I did a google search and go [this](http://watir.com/). Maybe its it? If so let us know, OP. @isherwood

Comment: Are you trying to locate an element by its class attribute or are you trying to get the class attribute of an element?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [**docs**](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Cheat-Sheet), it looks like you'd do this:

```
myEl = browser.link(:class, "trg-login")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should select you first element by class in this case selecting class 'navigation'

```
browser.uls(:class => "navigation")[0]
```